# Suggestion: Small subject change on question footer

Tags: feature-request

I'm not even sure suggestions are allowed on Meta, please forgive my newbie-ness.

Just a small sentence change in the question footer that shouldn't be hard but has me wincing all the time:

> Browse other questions tagged ... or ask your own question.

But what if this is my question?

> Browse other questions tagged ... or ask **another** question.

Pseudo-code "fix" (if anyone else on this planet cares):

```
ask " + ((IsLoggedIn && Question.Asker == User) ? "another" : "your own") + "question."
```

Comment: What I've noticed in reading this question is you failed to reasonably say "why" this needs to be done. Surely you're familiar with [the five whys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys) ... I don't think you need to do all five but some "why is this a problem" answers would be a good idea.

Comment: As an addition, the "Know someone who can answer?" blurb that's shown when there are no answers doesn't make much sense when it's your question either, since if you knew someone who could answer the question then it's unlikely that you would have asked it (or at least not have an answer to post for it).

Comment: Welcome to Meta, Lazlo! Don't worry, you're in the right place. Suggestions are a pretty big part of what goes on here.

Answer (score 1):

That message is not really for the person posting the question.  If you post a question you should have already browsed other questions with similar tags.